# Nested if statement in QGIS label expression

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, if-else

I'm trying to create labels for features, based on the value (or missing value) of three different columns and combinations can be possible.

I have three columns: Veg_dom, Veg_codom and Veg_onderg.

When all three columns have a value for a feature, I want the label to be as follows:

`Veg_dom$value + Veg_codom$value + (Veg_onderg$value)`.

Other possibilities should be
`Veg_dom$value + Veg_codom$value & Veg_dom$value + (Veg_onderg$value)`.

I use the following expression in the label expression window:

[image]

The labels however show as follows:
[image]

The only one correct is the first statement if all three columns have values.
Am I doing something wrong? Are nested `IF` statements allowed?

Expression:

```
if( Veg_codom <> ' ' AND  Veg_onderg <> ' ',
Veg_dom + '+' + Veg_codom + '+' + concat('(', Veg_onderg, ')'),

if( Veg_codom = ' ' AND  Veg_onderg <> ' ',
Veg_dom + '+' +concat('(', Veg_onderg, ')'),

if( Veg_codom <> ' ' AND  Veg_onderg = ' ',
Veg_dom + '+' + Veg_codom,

Veg_dom)))
```

Cels hold character-data:

[image]

Comment: It'd be helpful to know, what values your columns hold - especially how fields without values look like.

Comment: Thanks both. I added the expression as text and added a picture and description of the data in the cells.

Comment: Please don't post an answer in the top of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: Both the IF statements and the CASE statement work. I misused the = '' sign where I should have used IS NULL, to specify a cell is empty. So:

```
if( Veg_codom <> ' ' AND  Veg_onderg <> ' ',
Veg_dom + '+' + Veg_codom + '+' + concat('(', Veg_onderg, ')'),

if( Veg_codom IS NULL AND  Veg_onderg <> ' ',
Veg_dom + '+' +concat('(', Veg_onderg, ')'),

if( Veg_codom <> ' ' AND  Veg_onderg IS NULL,
Veg_dom + '+' + Veg_codom,

Veg_dom)))
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you need a `CASE` statement, which will allow you to have different conditions.

Something like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Veg_codon <> '' AND Veg_ondeg <> '' THEN Veg_dom + Veg_codom + '('+Veg_onderg+')'
    WHEN Veg_codon <> '' AND Veg_ondeg = '' THEN Veg_dom + Veg_codom + '(some default value)'
    WHEN Veg_codon = '' AND Veg_ondeg <> '' THEN Veg_dom + 'default value' + '('+Veg_onderg+')'
  ...
END
```